# Como faço para gerar automaticamente um favicon?

Tags: html, favicon

Olá, estou a criar uma API de login para clientes, quando o usuário gera "a pagina" ele faz upload da logo da sua empresa para o servidor, mas para alem de fazer upload da logo cria também gerar um favicon automaticamente, alguém tem ideia de como se faz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá.

Antigamente usava-se muito o favicon .ico, hoje em dias todos os browsers modernos já suportam png, o que inclusive fornece maior qualidade e flexibilidade.

Basta você redimensionar a imagem enviada pelo usuário e salvar em formato .png para já começar a usar. Você pode fazer em várias dimensões(16,32,64,96 etc..) mas o padrão é utilizar 32x32 pixels. Não sei qual linguagem programou sua API, mas existem bibliotecas que fazem isso ou outras APIs que fazem isso pra você.

Recomendo você oferecer um recurso que o usuário consiga recortar a área a ser utilizada dentro da imagem, pois o usuário pode enviar uma imagem com um espaçamento grande da logo até a borda, fazendo que ela menor ainda como favicon. O ideal é a logo estar o mais próximo da borda possível para melhor aproveitamento. Ou um outro campo destinado apenas a favicon mesmo.

Boa sorte.